# Different result between Date.yesterday and Date.today.prev_day and 1.day.ago in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am currently getting different results depend on which command I use to get the previous day. The only correct answer is `Date.today.prev_day`.

I can understand why `1.day.ago` and `Date.yesterday` might be different based on time zones, but I would expect normalized results from the two `Date` calls.

```
irb(main):026:0> Date.today.prev_day
=> Thu, 02 Mar 2017
irb(main):027:0> Date.yesterday
=> Fri, 03 Mar 2017
irb(main):028:0> 1.day.ago
=> Fri, 03 Mar 2017 02:45:05 UTC +00:00
```

Why am I getting different results with these three commands?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Being a `rails` extension `prev_day` is not usually available in `irb`. How are you loading it. For the last one `1.day.ago` is better understood as '86,400 seconds ago'.

Comment: @MarcRohloff I am just doing a `rails console`

Comment: @AlexanderLuna I was just wondering why the results are different for each. Sorry I wasn't more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It works as I would expect:

```
2.2.3 :007 > Rails.version
 => "4.2.6" 
2.2.3 :002 > Date.today
 => Sun, 05 Mar 2017 
2.2.3 :003 > Date.today.prev_day
 => Sat, 04 Mar 2017 
2.2.3 :004 > Date.yesterday
 => Sun, 05 Mar 2017 
2.2.3 :005 > 1.day.ago
 => Sun, 05 Mar 2017 00:10:13 UTC +00:00
```

I would start by checking the result of `Date.today`, i.e. is the issue in the `today` method or in the `prev_day` method. I would also check that the method hasn't been overridden somehow. You can do something like the following:

Date.today.method(:prev_day).source_location

Which returns `nil` for me.